# tvOS: shouldUpdateFocusInContext: not being called

Tags: focus, tableview, tvos

I have a `UITableView` and a `UIButton` on a tvOS view. According to [Apple's doco](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html) the `shouldUpdateFocusInContext:` should be called any time the focus changes.

However if I execute this code from the button:

```
[_tableViewController setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

tvOS generates a focus change from the button to the table view, however the `shouldUpdateFocusInContext:` method is not called on any controller or view that I can find.

My problem is that there are times when I want to enabled editing on the table view, but not set focus to it. Hence I want the `shouldUpdateFocusInContext:` method called so I can reject the focus change.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly I had the same issue with `shouldUpdateFocusInContext` and I switched to [this](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614945-tableview) method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UITableViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        //Where DetailTableCell is my custom UITableCell
        if let cell = context.nextFocusedView as? DetailTableCell {
            print("called next focused.")
        }

        if let previous = context.previouslyFocusedView as? DetailTableCell {
            print("Called previous focused.")
        }
    }
```

> Tells the delegate that a focus update specified by the context has
>   just occurred.